# receiving json data from web-service from unity 5

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I created a web-api in visual studio and created method which fetches data from sql database.

Here is the method written in visual studio which fetches the data.

```
public static DataTable GetQuestions()
        {
            string sprocName = "select * from Temp";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\Projects;Initial Catalog=SprocSystem;");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sprocName, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
            return dataTable;
        }
```

Here is the controller method:

```
public string GetQuestions()
        {
            DataTable dataTable = SprocDAL.GetQuestions();
            string ques = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
            return ques;
        }
```

I am using this link to access the results:

http://localhost:55197/api/sproc/GetQuestions

Now, I can see the output in my url as:

```
[{"Question":"inception","Option1":"opt1","Option2":"opt2","Option3":"opt3","Option4":"opt4","Answer":"opt2 "},{"Question":"another","Option1":"opt11","Option2":"opt22","Option3":"opt33","Option4":"opt44","Answer":"opt22 "}]
```

Now, I want to use this data in unity: 
Currently I am using this script to do this:

```
        string url = "http://localhost:55197/api/sproc/GetQuestions";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));

IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
    {
        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.data);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
        }    
    }
```

Now, when i run my unity module, i receive the following output in my debug window:

```
WWW Error: 401 Unauthorized
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<WaitForRequest>c__Iterator1:MoveNext() (at Assets/scripts/RacingGameScripts/carController.cs:116)
```

Any help on this.

Comment: I guess you need to host your API on some server instead of using localhost.

Comment: Have you tried putting a cross domain XML file?  What are you current build settings pointed too?